# How to replace part of xml using xmlstarlet?

Tags: xml, bash, shell, sh, xmlstarlet

I am trying to replace or swap part of xml using xmlstarlet.
Here is an example of before and after.

**Before:**

```
<root>
  <catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
    </book>
  </catalog>

<keys>
  <key>
    <name>Robert D. Wilsey</name>
    <street>4854 Charter Street</street>
  </key>
  <key>
    <name>Elizabeth Fletcher</name>
    <street>1528 Station Street</street>
  </key>
</keys>
</root>
```

**After:**

```
<root>
  <catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
    </book>
  </catalog>

<objects>
  <object>
    <guid>55866ddd-7601-42b6-8b6b-a2adfaa01125</guid>
  </object>
</objects>
</root>
```

**Script:**

```
read -r -d '' XML <<"EOF"
<root>
  <catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
    </book>
  </catalog>

<keys>
  <key>
    <name>Robert D. Wilsey</name>
    <street>4854 Charter Street</street>
  </key>
  <key>
    <name>Elizabeth Fletcher</name>
    <street>1528 Station Street</street>
  </key>
</keys>
</root>
EOF

xmlstarlet ed -u '//root\keys' -v "
<objects>
  <object>
    <guid>55866ddd-7601-42b6-8b6b-a2adfaa01125</guid>
  </object>
</objects>
" <<< "$XML"
```

Comment: Your XML is not valid because of two roots (root and keys).

Comment: xmlstarlet can't edit invalid xml?

Comment: xmlstarlet requires valid XML.

Comment: Alright, updated.